# SQL Server - Selecting a Primary Key for my table

Tags: sql-server, performance, database-design, indexing, primary-key

I have a table that stores user info.
In the User table, username is unique. Do you think I should make username as primarykey or should I use a surrogate key that is an int?
Would using a string key hit performance badly?

Comment: This is the kind of question that starts religious wars. If `username` is a key in the logical model them make it a key in the implementation i.e. at least a `UNIQUE`, maybe the `PRIMARY KEY`. If you have multiple candidate keys then all should be implemented and the choice of which to promote to 'primary' is arbitrary. If you choose to add a surrogate, you first need a natural key (and `username` sounds reasonable) but be sure to know why you think you need a surrogate :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use a surrogate integer key.

Usernames won't change that often, but they could.

As to performance, don't worry about that until you know you have a problem.

SQL Server will create the clustered index on the Primary key column by default. If you use a wide key in the clustered index, all non-clustered indexes will also contain that wide key.

Comment: In my case I am thinking not to let users change their login name. Their first & last names can be changed but the registered name cant be. Should I still go with int pk?

Comment: For clarification: In that case, dont you think I am ending up with an additional column? Will that not hit performance? Or may be I am concentrating too much on performance while leaving other important aspects! Can you shed light on what I may be missing? Thanks!

Comment: Oh the nativity of my younger self!

Answer (score 6):

Generally using an int as the primary key.  This is due in part to convention as well as saving space when using them as foreign keys in other tables.  In reality, using your username field as the primary wouldn't hurt performance unless you wind up having thousands of records in multiple tables using it.  If you think your tables will remain small, its up to preference.

Answer (score 4):

I would use an identity surrogate primary key and cluster on that.  The clustered index is included in all indexes and should be narrow, static and increasing.

As far as a primary key, you COULD make the username the primary key, BUT since foreign keys will reference it, you also want it to be static (which a username is not).  So I would make a non-clustered unique index on username.  The identity PK will automatically be included in the NCI.

I would include any other columns in that same index (as included columns) depending upon usage patters where access is primarily by username - for instance, the password hash, maybe the name.  But I'd check the execution plans, use the profiler and/or the index tuning wizard with expected workloads.